# Is this broken pipe the reason my freezer is not working? Can it be fixed?

Tags: appliances

The freezer is old, but I am a renter so I couldn't say how old. On the back there is a sticker that says “HUAYI B43CB”;

[image: label on back]

It has been stopping intermittently for the last week, and in the last two days it has not come on at all. Everything is now room temperature. It dosen’t have a light, but it is certainly plugged in and switched on.

Looking inside I see that one of the pipes in the shelf of the freezer is broken;
[image: view of whole freezer]
[image]

Is this why the freezer is not working? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That broken pipe has let all the refrigerant escape, so it will no longer work.

Compared to the cost of a new one, the repair will likely be more expensive given the time, tools and materials involved.

Comment: I'm glad I don't have to attempt a repair, thanks for letting me know.